# Weird behavior running code via function

Tags: python, api, python-requests, mediawiki

I have a function to get article's text from wikimedia api

```
def get_content(lang, title):
    url = "https://"+ lang +".wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    params={'action':'query', 'format':'json', 'titles': title, 'prop': 
        'linkshere','redirects':'true','prop':'extracts','exlimit':'max','explaintext':'true'}
    response = requests.get(url=url,params=params).json()
    content = response["query"]["pages"]
    content = six.next(six.itervalues(content))['extract']
    return content
```

however when I call this function, errors occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 640,
in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 287, in i
ncrement
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xn--mesut%20zil-57a.wikipedia.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?
exlimit=max&titles=en&action=query&format=json&prop=extract
s&redirects=true&explaintext=true (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHT
TPSConnection object at 0x7f7a5e74c0b8>: Failed to establish a new 
connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not kno
wn',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "get_data.py", line 165, in <module>
print(get_content('Mesut Özil','en'))
File "get_data.py", line 147, in get_content
response = request_get_data(url=url,params=params).json()
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/klux/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xn--
mesut%20zil-57a.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?
exlimit=max&titles=en&action=query&format=json
&prop=extracts&redirects=true&explaintext=true (Caused by 
NewConnectionError
('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection o
bject at 0x7f7a5e74c0b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
-2] Name or service not known',))
```

Firstly, I thought I was blocked by wikimedia for calling too much requests but when I run that code in "main function", it works perfectly like this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lang = 'en'
    title = 'Mesut Özil'
    url = "https://"+ lang +".wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    params={'action':'query', 'format':'json', 'titles': title, 'prop': 'linkshere',
            'redirects':'true','prop':'extracts','exlimit':'max','explaintext':'true'}
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params).json()
    content = response["query"]["pages"]
    content = six.next(six.itervalues(content))['extract']
    print(content)
```

Output:

```
Mesut Özil (German pronunciation: [ˈmeːzut ˈøːzil], Turkish: [meˈsut 
ˈøzil]; born 15 October 1988) is a German fo
otballer who plays for English club Arsenal and the German national 
team...
```

I don't know how to solve this weird behavior, I tried to debug by visual studio code and `response` variable in `get_content` function turned to `undefined`. So someone has any solution for this situation ?

Comment: Unfortunately your code snippet lacks the context necessary for reproducing or solving the problem. In its current state, it is impossible to write a constructive solution and as such the question is not useful for other readers. I am voting to close the question. If you choose to improve it, the question will be added automatically to the reopen queue. Please consult these two pages for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is declared:

```
def get_content(lang, title):
```

But I see in your traceback:

```
print(get_content('Mesut Özil','en'))
```

I'm fairly certain that there is no such site as `https://Mesut Özil.wikipedia.org`

Comment: Opps, this dumb mistake caused me headaches, thanks a lot.